# Date format in hql

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I have hql like

```
hql="SELECT DISTINCT C FROM Client C 
WHERE lower(str(C.name)) like '%"+sSearch
+ "%' OR str(day(C.birthday)) like '%"+sSearch "%';
```

As you can see, i can search sSearch in my table.

But problem is that sSearch can have dd.MM.yyyy format or can not be a date (e.g. sSearch="John"), and DATE type has yyyy-MM-dd format in DB.

I want to select date in needed format dd.MM.yyyy as string for using expression 'like'.

Thanks.

Solved this problem with

```
hql="SELECT DISTINCT C FROM Client C 
WHERE lower(str(C.name)) like '%"+sSearch
+ "%' OR concat(str(day(C.birthday)),'.',str(month(C.birthday)),'.',
str(year(C.birthday))) like '%"+sSearch "%';
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a Dateformat to format the date String.

```
DateFormat dateFormat1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyy");
DateFormat dateFormat2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date d = dateFormat1.parse(sSearch);

hql="SELECT DISTINCT C FROM Client C 
WHERE lower(str(C.name)) like '%"+sSearch
+ "%' OR str(day(C.birthday)) like '%"+ dateFormat2.format(d) +"%';
```

Answer (score -1):

if you are using mysql, you can use mysql, you can use date_format .

```
"select dictinct c from Client c where lower(str(C.name)) like '%" + sSearch + "%' or
date_format(C.birthday,'%d.%m.%Y') lkie '%" + sSearch +"%'"
```

but I prefer to convert the sSearch to String  like 'yyyy-MM-dd' on service layer or controller layer, thoughs i can use code like this.

```
" ... C.birtyday like '%"+ sSearch + "%'"
```

Comment: DB-specific SQL is not relevant to HQL